# Unable to read rows in tables from database in Java

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing code to implement a model for inventory. As part of that I have to get Items from database and set the properties of the Item and add that Item objects to the list an perform few functions on the list. There are three tables in the database and each contains 3 rows each. But the problem is that only the last row in the last table is getting inserted all the nine times.
Please help me find where the problem is in the code.
The method readAllItemsFromDb has to the task above mentioned and return a list of Item objects. The Item class contains fields like id, description, weight, price, manufacturingDate, useBeforeMonths and their set and get methods.

My code for the method is as follows--

```
public List<Item> readAllItemsFromDb() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    List<Item> list=new ArrayList<Item>();
    Item item=new Item();
    Milk milk=new Milk();
    Cheese cheese=new Cheese();
    Wheat wheat=new Wheat();

    String cheese_type=new String();
    String milk_type=new String();
    String wheat_type=new String();
    String ingred_cheese=new String();

    String cheese_query="select id,description,weight,price,mfg_date,UseBeforeInMonths from cheese_tbl;";
    String milk_query="select id,description,weight,price,mfg_date,UseBeforeInMonths from milk_tbl;";
    String wheat_query="select id,description,weight,price,mfg_date,UseBeforeInMonths from wheat_tbl;";

    try {
        con=dcm.getConnection();//Theres' no problem with Connection 
        st=con.createStatement();
        rs=st.executeQuery(cheese_query);
        while(rs.next()){
            item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
            item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
            item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
            item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
            item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));

            list.add(item);
        }

        rs=st.executeQuery(milk_query);
        while(rs.next()){
            item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
            item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
            item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
            item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
            item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));
            list.add(item);

        }

        rs=st.executeQuery(wheat_query);
        while(rs.next()){
            item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
            item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
            item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
            item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
            item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));

            list.add(item); 
        }


    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return list;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new Item object at the start of each iteration in your while loop(s).

```
   while(rs.next()){
        item = new Item();
        item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
        item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
        item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
        item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
        item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));

        list.add(item);
    }

    rs=st.executeQuery(milk_query);
    while(rs.next()){
        item = new Item();
        item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
        item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
        item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
        item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
        item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));

        list.add(item);
    }

    rs=st.executeQuery(wheat_query);
    while(rs.next()){
        item = new Item();
        item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
        item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
        item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
        item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
        item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));

        list.add(item); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you use always the same Item object, you need to create a `new Item()` for each `rs.next()` call.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one instance of object  Item item=new Item(); at begin of function then in each while there is used the same object item. In each while loop iteration you need to create new object instance that will be added to list;

```
while(rs.next()){
        item = new Item(); //this one 
        item.setId(rs.getInt(1));
        item.setDescription(rs.getString(2));
        item.setWeight(rs.getFloat(3));
        item.setPrice(rs.getFloat(4));
        item.setManufacturingDate(rs.getDate(5));
        item.setUseBeforeMonths(rs.getInt(6));

        list.add(item); 
    }
```